# Цитируемые вопросы

Tags: поддержка

В меню есть "Цитируемые вопросы". Как подсчитывается "цитируемость"? Где можно увидеть эту цифру?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, это связано с вопросами, которые часто дублируется. Например, есть вопрос, у которого часто появляются дублеты. Когда один из них закрывают, у другого, связанного с ним, повышается индекс цитируемости.

Также, кажется, этот показатель связан с количеством переходов по ссылке, которая генерируется для каждого пользователя при нажатии на "поделиться".

*По материалам https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172728/379531.*